# ANDROID SDK is not found after installed android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

i just installed android studio 4.1.

when start, app prompts to select Android SDK, and i browse

```
c:\user\appdata\local
```

there is no android folder

is that because the machine does not has internet connection and some files not downloaded?

if so, where can i get android sdk installed?

Comment: yes usually android studio downloaded sdk on first initialize, so try restart android studio with connection enabled

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat my machine not allowed to have internet connection, what is the solution? android studio download page does not has the sdk installer.

Comment: maybe copy sdk from other machine then setting path to new sdk